# Java: Sort ArrayList with nested HashMap by value

Tags: java

I have a `ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>`, which I want to sort by the value of the HashMap. What would be the quickest way to do this in Java (with the least amount of code)?

Comment: Which value of the HashMap?  It may have many values, in an undefined iteration order.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Thanks for your quick response. My ArrayList looks like this: `[{Name=Pete, Score=1}, {Name=Joe, Score=5}, {Name=Henry, Score=4}]` and I want to sort by score.

Comment: It looks like you want a custom object with two fields `name` and `score` rather than a `Map<String, String>`.

Comment: what are your ideas so far? for example you could look at Collections.sort() or at a Comparator-based approach; you could then measure runtime performance for inputs of different sizes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using Java 8, you'd probably be best off writing

```
list.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(map -> Integer.parseInt(map.get("Score"))));
```

If not, you're probably best off writing

```
Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Map<String, String>>() {
   @Override public int compare(Map<String, String> a, Map<String, String> b) {
      return Integer.compare(
         Integer.parseInt(a.get("Score")),
         Integer.parseInt(b.get("Score")));
   }
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much! What if I wanted to do this for the Name, which is a string?

Comment: Then just write `Comparator.comparing(map -> map.get("Name"))`.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm using Android Studio, which doesn't have Java 8. What would be the non-Java 8 version?

Comment: Them the body of your `compare` method is just `return a.get("Name").compareTo(b.get("Name"))`.

Comment: @Algorithm_NL This answer is great for your stated question, but you'd be better off following Paul Boddington's comment and replace the `HashMap` with a custom object with two fields `name` and `score`. You can then make the object implement `Comparable` and you won't need an anonymous `Comparator`.

Comment: @Andreas I know, but the problem is that that would be difficult to read with a simpleAdapter into a ListView in Android. You're making a good point though, thanks!